# C++ - no matching function for call to <class method>

Tags: c++, pointers, compiler-errors, pointer-to-member

I get the compiler error below from the following code.

```
cube.cpp:94: error: no matching function for call to 'Animation::animate(CUBE_ARRAY&, uint8_t&, uint8_t&, CUBE_STATE&)'
animation.h:28: note: candidates are: virtual uint8_t Animation::animate(CUBE_ARRAY*, uint8_t, uint8_t, CUBE_STATE)
```

---

There is a class `Animation` with a method:

```
28 virtual uint8_t animate(CUBE_ARRAY *arrayP, uint8_t transIn, uint8_t transOut, CUBE_STATE startState);
```

This is being called by the line:

```
94 animationComplete = animationPointer -> animate(cubeArray, transIn, transOut, state);
```

`animationPointer` is set to point to an instance of the `Raindrops` class which inherits from `Animation`:

```
animationPointer = &raindrops;
```

and it's original definition is:

```
Animation *animationPointer;
```

As far as my (limited!) understanding of pointers goes this should work: `raindrops` should be located at the address pointed to by `animationPointer`, and `->` should then give the result of the `animate` method. So I'm not sure why the compiler is seeing the call as having arguments passed by reference.

What is doubly confusing is that I have very similar code which is assumed to work (I don't have a way of testing this, it's an embedded application and I'm converting code from one MCU type to another).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message suggests you are supposed to do

```
animationComplete = animationPointer->animate(
    &cubeArray, transIn, transOut, state);
```

Note the ampersand in front of `cubeArray`.